# Переопределение метода в PHP

Tags: ооп, php, методы

Возник вопрос при изучении паттернов проектирования для PHP:
Можно ли обычный метод в абстрактном классе переопределить в процессе наследования другим абстрактным методом, который в дальнейшем будет определяться конкретной реализацией класса?

Например:

```
abstract class One{
    public function methodOne(){
        /// реализация
    }
}

abstract class Two extends One{
    abstract public function methodOne();
}

class Three extends Two{
    public function methodOne(){/// реализация для класса three }
}
```

Comment: Что вас удерживает от самостоятельной проверки этого фрагмента кода?

Comment: Проверял, выдает ошибку
Cannot make non abstract method One::methodOne() abstract in class Two in [...][...] on line 21
Собственно и возникло такое предположение что нельзя так делать..
Разбираю шаблоны написанные на Java и пробую делать реализацию в PHP
В примере для Java такое прокатывает

Comment: нельзя делать из public abstract (зачем это вообще может понадобиться ?), наоборот можно.

Comment: паттерн декоратор, в оригинале метод One::methodOne() наследуется так же классами не реализующими этот метод. Ок, тогда буду делать его абстрактным в классе One, а в остальных методах где требуется делать реализацию которая была представлена в One. Спасибо!

Comment: нет, в абстрактном наследнике вы можете либо реализовать этот метод, либо пропустить. переопределить таким образом не получится. вообще, у вас явная ошибка в архитектуре, выкладывайте весь код